# AS3 Access of undefined property event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm learning AS3 maybe this a simple question but I can't find what is wrong...

I receive this error

> Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 1   1120: Access of undefined property event.

this is my code and my MC instance name is Rueda_mc

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var Rueda_mc:MovieClip

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotar);
function rotar(evento: Event): void {
Rueda_mc.rotation += 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for interest! I found the problem i have some previous code in other layer hidden so that make the conflict!

Thanks and hope see you soon!

Comment: If you want to comment on answer, you should use add comment button below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var Rueda_mc:MovieClip;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotar);


function rotar(event:Event): void {
    Rueda_mc.rotation += 10;
}
```